# Paypal developer account confirmation email is not sent

Tags: paypal

When I create new app on my paypal developer account , this message appears to me

Email confirmation needed: To create an app, confirm your email address. We sent you an email with instructions on how to confirm your email address. Alternatively, go to paypal.com to confirm your email.

and nothing is sent to my mail
thanks

Comment: Have you contacted PayPal? This appears to have nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I thought that may be it is a frequently problem that anyone here can help me instead of contacting them

Comment: Can anyone tell reason for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52288866/create-app-on-paypal-disabled-after-confirming-email

Answer (score 1):

If your live Paypal email is still unconfirmed it won't allow you to create an app. You can manually send out a confirmation email by going to https://www.paypal.com/profile and under the email section click on confirm to send out the email again. It's not a programming issue. If that doesn't work just call PayPal customer service and they can do it over the phone

Comment: I already called them
they told me that I need to confirm the account with my credit card number or bank account even if it is a a developer account !